# Unable to access a websocket using ESP8266 (Using Arduino IDE)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I been trying to get my ESP8266 to connect to a websocket, but no luck so far. Things that are ruled out are:

1. The ESP8266 is connected to WiFi and has access to Internet (checked using a HTTP request).
2. Not a problem with the socket server, I spun up my own websocket server and it was not hit.
3. Tried port 80 and 443.

My code is as follows, keeps printing

> Not Connected!

:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "WebSocketClient.h"
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
    
WebSocketClient ws(true);
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("SSID", "PASSWORD");
    
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
}
    
void loop() {
  if (!ws.isConnected()) {
    ws.connect("echo.websocket.org", "/", 80);
    Serial.println("Not connected!");
  } else {
    ws.send("hello");
    
    String msg;
    if (ws.getMessage(msg)) {
      Serial.println(msg);
    }
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebSocketClient ws(true);` tries to connect securely and uses `WiFiClientSecure` in stead of `WiFiClient`. This will probably require specifying a certificate or some such.

Try `WebSocketClient ws(false);` to see if that works (tries to force an insecure connection).

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I had been scratching my head whole day !

Comment: I ran into a new problem now, hope you don't mind helping me! I got a server running at [link](https://repl.it/@DeepakR/NecessaryJuvenileLamp#index.js) and it works fine, checked using [link](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html). But I am once again unable to access the server using the same code which worked for `wss://echo.websocket.org`.

Comment: No time atm, sorry, just a few tips: use port 80 if you can, use ws: for unsecure and wss: for secure, and maybe pose a new question here.